# problem in commenting a post with instaPy

Tags: comments, instagram, instapy

i am trying to comment on a specific post in instagram
here is my code :

```
from instapy import InstaPy

insta_username = "username"
insta_password = "password"

session = InstaPy(username=insta_username, password=insta_password)
session.login()

# set up all the settings
session.set_relationship_bounds(enabled=True,delimit_by_numbers=True)
session.set_comments(['aMEIzing!', 'So much fun!!', 'Nicey!'])
session.set_do_comment(enabled=True, percentage=85)

session.interact_by_URL(urls=["https://www.instagram.com/p/CDBdLvUpTYu/?igshid=2im20zz3lvz5"], randomize=False, interact=True)
print("done")
# end the bot session
session.end()
```

this is what i get :

*INFO [2021-05-06 02:18:32] [username] --> Image already liked!

INFO [2021-05-06 02:18:32] [username] Liked: 0

INFO [2021-05-06 02:18:32] [username] Already Liked: 1

INFO [2021-05-06 02:18:32] [username] Commented: 0

INFO [2021-05-06 02:18:32] [username] Followed: 0

INFO [2021-05-06 02:18:32] [username] Inappropriate: 0

INFO [2021-05-06 02:18:32] [username] Not valid users: 0*

can someone plaese help me figure out why it doesnt comment anything!!

Answer (score 0):

Set this option as well:

```
session.set_user_interact(amount=6, randomize=True, percentage=72, media='Photo')
```

amount, percentage can be changed as per you configuration